# How to select field based from combobox in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I want a user to be able to choose the field they select from a table through the use of a combo box in an MS Access form. My combo box contains a list of all the field names in the table, and when the user selects one I want that field to be queried. Currently, the general syntax of my code looks like this but doesn't return any values when I run it.

```
SELECT FORMS![formName]!cboName 
FROM tblName;
```

The form is working fine as far as I can tell so I'm pretty sure the issue is with my SQL but I can't figure out where. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is this SQL - in a query object? Field names cannot be dynamic in query object design. Query objects can be modified with VBA and QueryDefs. But then would have to also modify ControlSource of textbox to display field on form.

Comment: @June7, yes the SQL is in a query object. I am not too familiar with VBA or QueryDefs however. Could you please explain more? Thank you.

Comment: Suggest you research the topic of programmatically modifying query object. Why would user need to be able to select field as opposed to inputting filter parameter to select records?